# How can I shorten resource bundle calls? Composite component?

Tags: java, jsf, resourcebundle

I'm not really happy with the built-in JSF resource bundle possibilities, like:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{messages['form.label.create']}">
```

Therefore I tried to code my own composite component to shorten these things:

```
<composite:interface>

    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    <composite:attribute name="p1" />

</composite:interface>


<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputFormat value="#{messages['cc.attrs.value']}"> //text.properties
        <f:param value="#{cc.attrs.p1}" />
    </h:outputFormat>
</composite:implementation>
```

Usage:

```
<cc:messages value="label.name" p1="#{test}" />
```

But the expression `messages['cc.attrs.value']` looks up in resource bundle for cc.attrs.* instead of fetching the value content.

Can I forget about my approach? Has anyone an idea how to do similar things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing `messages[cc.attrs.value]` instead.

JSF is interpreting `'cc.attrs.value'` as a string value not a variable name.